# Laravel 5.8 whereHasMorph "dot" syntax not supported?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Laravel 5.8 introduced `whereHasMorph` for querying polymorphic relationships. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

I might be missing something, but it doesn't seem to support dot syntax.

In a regular relationship, I would be able to do something like:

```
$comments->whereHasMorph(
'video.someRelationship', function ($query) {
    $query->where(...);
});
```

But with whereHasMorph that doesn't seem to work:

```
$comments->whereHasMorph(
    'commentable.someRelationship',
    [Video::class, Audio::class],
    function ($query) {
        $query->where(...);
    }
);
```

If it's indeed not supported, is there a way around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`whereHasMorph()` doesn't (and can't) support the "dot syntax".

Use `whereHas()` inside the closure for the nested relationship:

```php
$comments->whereHasMorph(
    'commentable',
    [Video::class, Audio::class],
    function ($query) {
        $query->where(...) // Constraint on "commentable"
            ->whereHas('someRelationship', function ($query) {
                $query->where(...); // Constraint on "someRelationship"
            });
    }
);
```

Comment: I have a followup question. if in Audio "someRelationship" is a `belongsTo`, while in Video "someRelationship" is an attribute (`return $this->parent->someRelationship`), is there a way to make `whereHas('someRelationship',...)` work?

Comment: Yes, you can differentiate depending on the polymorphic type. Take a look at the documentation, the closure receives the type as the second parameter.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, i was hoping i could generalize it by defining "someRelationship" differently in each of the Models so that i wouldn't have to check the type in all the whereHas queries.

Comment: That would be possible, but only if `someRelationship` is a real relationship in both cases.

Comment: Yeah i guess this is a good example of "belongsToThrough" being helpful, because right now I couldn't define `this->parent->someRelationship` as a relationship.